# AngularJS lost css class during model update (DOM re-draw)

Tags: javascript, jquery, model, angularjs, toggleclass

I've got a table whose rows loop thru some model data. Onclick of a table cell, all the cells of that row toggle `.active` (background becomes red). That works fine (although I'll eventually add a more sophisticated checker that removes `.active` from all of the row's siblings). However, my table is receiving data via WebSocket pushes/messages that update the model and cause the table to be re-drawn. When this happens, my "selection" is lost.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'time':true">
  <td
    ng-click="items[$index].active =! items[$index].active"
    ui-refresh="items[$index].active"
    ui-jq="toggleClass"
    ui-options="'active'"
  >{{item.time | date:'hh:mm a'}}</td>
  <td
    ng-click="items[$index].active =! items[$index].active"
    ui-refresh="items[$index].active"
    ui-jq="toggleClass"
    ui-options="'active'"
  >
    <a href="#/items/details/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In my controller, the new WebSocket message is pushed my array `items`:

```
function Items($scope , WebSocket)
{
  $scope.items = [];

  WebSocket.on('items', function(data)
  {// receive a bunch of items onload
    $scope.items = data.items;
  });

  WebSocket.on('item', function(data)
  {// receive subsequent items as they are pushed
    $scope.items.push(data.item);
  });
}
```

So I'm wondering why `items[$index].active` does not persist thru the DOM re-draw (and retain its `active` css class). Also if anyone has a solution as to how I can persist my "state", that would be great.

Usually I loose the css class altogether, but sometimes (seemingly randomly) it re-appears on a new row in the same position of the table (say 2nd row) as the original row, even though the original row has been shifted down (to what is then the 5th row) and the new row that `active` appears on didn't exist when `active` was added.

I would post an example, but neither Plunkr nor jsfiddle support NodeJS (which pushes out the WebSocket messages) and is necessary to demonstrate the behaviour.

### Solution

Based on [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14948533/758177), I modified my controller slightly to add a second array:

```
function Items($scope , WebSocket)
{
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.rowSelection = [];// <- THIS IS NEW

  WebSocket.on('items', function(data)
  {// receive a bunch of items onload
    $scope.items = data.items;
  });

  WebSocket.on('item', function(data)
  {// receive subsequent items as they are pushed
    $scope.items.push(data.item);
  });
}
```

And in my template, swapped `items[$index].active` for `rowSelection[$index]` (since the sole purpose of this second array is to remember who is selected/active, it doesn't need an `active` property).

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to toggle the row instead of having each cell manage same thing?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, it would. Except Bootstrap applies background colour to table cells instead of rows :(

Comment: not hard to adjust your css for cells based on active class on row... is less heavy lifting for script

Comment: @charlietfl, sorry i don't understand what you said ('not hard to adjust your css for cells based on active class on row'); are you saying what I'm trying to do is not difficult?

Comment: i'm saying that changing css applied by boootstrap is very simple

Comment: @charlietfl, yes that is true, but then it can start to sprawl: Bootstrap has lots of good ideas but often terrible implementation.

Comment: sprawl? You're talking about one or 2 css rules vs having far more listeners than needed, pretty standard stuff for any site.

Comment: @charlietfl, I mean there are a bunch of other dumb things like that in bootstrap that I would change, so it opens a can of worms. We decided this morning that we're going to clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing the values in `items[$index].active` because the whole items array is being overwritten when the WebSocket updates.

To keep the selected status, you should store this in a separate variable that is not affected.

Something like:

In controller

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.itemStatus = [];
```

In directive/template

```
  <td
    ng-click="itemStatus[item.id].active =! itemStatus[item.id].active"
    ui-refresh="itemStatus[item.id].active"
```

Comment: I originally thought my whole array was being re-written, but then when I looked at the controller again, I remembered that the second function (which handles subsequent pushes) only adds to the array: `$scope.items.push(data.item);`. Also, your suggestion causes a TypeError: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'active' of undefined` because `itemStatus[item.id]` doesn't get defined as an object before one of its properties is set.

Comment: I dropped the `active` property altogether to solve this issue. See updated question with the solution I implemented.